# ICS Method CANCEL causes errors in multiple Calendar apps

Tags: icalendar

I want to add an event to a calendar using an ICS-file and remove with another.

The content of the file I used to add:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20210914T095500Z
DTSTART:20210914T200000
DTEND:20210914T210000
ORGANIZER:mailto:organizer@organizer.com
ATTENDEE:mailto:attendee@attendee.com
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
UID:95ef400d-e3f3-4d94-b99a-914390b098d2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This successfully adds the event to the calendar.
I then try to remove it with the following:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20210914T095500Z
DTSTART:20210914T200000
DTEND:20210914T210000
ORGANIZER:mailto:organizer@organizer.com
ATTENDEE:mailto:attendee@attendee.com
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CANCELLED
UID:95ef400d-e3f3-4d94-b99a-914390b098d2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This causes an issue in:
Outlook (online version): Error Message: The events couldn't be imported. Try again later.
Google Calendar: No error message, but does not remove the event either.
Windows Calendar: Error Message: The file may be damaged. (Translated into English)

It works in Outlook 2016.

How do I need to change my ICS, so it works properly?

Comment: Are all your lines 75 characters &  folded correctly?  Does the file have type text/calendar? Also the .ics is not completely valid:   https://icalendar.org/validator.html says:

    Missing required PRODID property near line # 1Reference: RFC 5545 3.6. Calendar Components
    Missing required VERSION property near line # 1Reference: RFC 5545 3.6. Calendar Components

Comment: @anmari I have tried with PRODID and VERSION. It makes no difference. It does have MIME-Type text/calendar if sent as an email-attachment. What do you mean with "folded correctly"?

Answer (score 0):

> When used in a MIME message entity, the value of this property MUST be the same as the Content-Type "method" parameter value. If either the "METHOD" property or the Content-Type "method" parameter is specified, then the other MUST also be specified. [source](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-7-2-method.html)

Your ics-files are correct, and they work:
[after sending both](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsdie.png)( in german but it says, "Delete from calendar" )
You probably have the wrong content-type in your attachment

```
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method="CANCEL"
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="related_events/related_events_canceled.ics"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

QkVHSU46VkNBTEVOREFSCk...
```

your file has **METHOD:CANCEL**, so your attachment should also have the method set.

You are missing some params like VERSION or PRODID, but the ics file as you have posted them work for me in gmail and outlook, so this missing method is the only thing, that I can think of. Since the event is getting added, as you sad, I assume that the content-type of your email is correct and so should work on both REQUEST AND CANCEL.